# How to transfer spritesheets in unity without losing settings

Tags: unity3d

I have a character with a sprite, animations, etc that I want to transfer into a new unity file. However, if I copy and paste or import the character's spritesheets and animations, they lose their settings and the individual sprites on the spritesheet are no longer sectioned into the different sprites. Is there any easy way to transfer the character and any files/sprites it requires while keeping the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the assets as a [Custom Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html#ExportingPackages) to preserve all the asset information like settings and links to other assets.

How to create a custom package for exporting

1. In your project menu click on **Assets > Export Package** to bring up the **Exporting Package** dialog box.
2. From this dialog box, select the assets you want to include in the custom package by checking the check boxes.

   > **Note**: Make sure you leave **Include Dependencies** ticked to auto select any assets used by the assets you have selected.
3. Click on **Export** to bring up the File Explorer and choose where you want to store this custom package.
4. Import the custom package into your new project.